# Using checkpoint

Tags: developer-console

Following is the class I am using for checkpoint and executing the same from developer console. I am unable to see any checkpoint values as shown in the image below:  [image: debug console].

```
public class checkpoinTest {
    public string checkpointVar {get;set;}
    public checkpoinTest()
    {
        checkpointVar = 'Value1';
        function2();
    }
    public void function2()
    {
        checkpointVar = 'Value2';
    }
}
```

Can you please suggest how can i see the checkpoint value here in developer console. Using checkpoints on line 5 and 9. Thanks.

Comment: Where's your code that calls the class? The class doesn't run by itself unless it's instantiated

Comment: @crmprogdev - in debug - Execute anonymous window I am calling checkpoinTest chk = new checkpoinTest(); and then I am able to view the checkpoint in debug log without any value.

Answer (score 2):

First, checkpoints are not created by assigning values to "checkpoint" variables in your code; essentially the equivalent of creating debug statements. Checkpoints are used to evaluate the values of variables at points of execution in your code. You can select up to five lines in your code to set checkpoints to capture the values in your variables as your code executes. You might think of this as taking a "snapshot" of what's held in memory just before that line executes (checkpoint is *before* execution, *not* after).

**Note:** to capture checkpoints, it's essential to **set the Apex Log Level** to **Finer** or **Finest**. Be aware that checkpoints only capture information the first time a line executes. This is important to consider when a checkpoint is placed on a line contained within a loop.

One cannot create a checkpoint in code which hasn't been saved in the [Source Code Editor](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=code_dev_console_view_code_editor.htm&language=en_US#code_dev_console_view_code_editor) (see image at top of page and note the red dots beside line numbers). Once code as been saved in the editor, you click in the margin to the left of the line number in the [Source Code Editor](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=code_dev_console_view_code_editor.htm&language=en_US#code_dev_console_view_code_editor) where you want to set the checkpoint. With the Developer Console open when the code executes, you can then view the checkpoints and results in the [Checkpoints Tab](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=code_dev_console_tab_checkpoints.htm&language=en_US). See [Setting Checkpoints in Apex Code](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=code_dev_console_checkpoints_setting.htm&language=en_US) for more.

Comment: I understand your answer.. but I am not sure why the checkpoin values are not showing here. I have set the system.debug statement to 'Finer'. Also it does not show the values after checking with the foor loop in the code  - 
 public class checkpoinTest1 {
    public string checkpointVar {get;set;}
    public checkpoinTest1()
    {
        checkpointVar = 'Value1';
        function2();
    }
    public void function2()
    {
        checkpointVar = 'Value2';
        for(Integer i = 0; i<=10; i++)
        {
            i = i+1;
        }
    }
}

Comment: Add `system.debug('checkpointVar = ' + checkpointVar);` under each of the lines where you have `checkpointVar` in your class. Then set debugging back to Debug and they will show up for all of your tests and iterations. You are NOT creating Apex check points, they are just variables. They are also defined as strings with getters and setters, implying they should be called from a visualforce page. Suggest you create a real test class to call these from with test data & not execute anonymous.